# Mapbox maps are blurry than Openstreet Maps => Satelite image as background

Tags: mapbox, openstreetmap, mapbox-ios, satellite-image, mapbox-studio

I am developing an iOS app where I have to show maps with custom color coded tracks for different Parks. I have found that Openstreet maps allow such customisations but they want me to publish these changes live on Openstreet maps which I don't want.

I checked Mapbox allows customisations to Openstreet maps in much more flexible ways and I am learning that through Mapbox studio. However, while laying custom paths and tracks, I found that Satelite image for Mapbox maps are blurrier than Openstreet maps. I have attached images from Mapbox and Openstreet maps at same zoom levels - 20.

You can also check resolutions from below links,
OpenStreet Maps: https://www.openstreetmap.org/edit?editor=id#map=20/35.6111733/-87.0855939
Mapbox Maps: https://studio.mapbox.com/styles/pareshthakor/ckpia8vg005ks17mvmcah9gkx/edit/#20/35.6111733/-87.0855939/0/1

If you were unable to access above links I have attached relevant images as well.

**OpenStreet Map:**

[image]

**Mapbox Map:**

[image]

Please let me know if I could match Satelite map resolution on Mapbox or not if Mapbox is using Openstreet maps as its base. This is critical for me because without such detailed Satelite image, I can't show proper info to users.

Let me know if you need anything else from me to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

The aerial imagery in the first screenshot doesn't come from OpenStreetMap! OpenStreetMap doesn't provide aerial imagery. Open the background settings in the iD editor (shortcut: B) and you will see the source for this aerial imagery. It could be Esri or Bing, for example.

Comment: Thanks @scai. I am able to check OpenStreet Map uses Bing for Aerial imagery. I wonder how I can customise Aerial imagery for Mapbox. So, instead of default aerial imagery can I use Bing map for aerial imagery? As Bing maps cover some detailed info for places which I want in map. I tried to use NAIP aerial images but that does not help. Bing is much more clear than NAIP. It would be good if I can just customise aerial imagery for the place I want. Means, Aerial imagery from Bing only for Maury County Park.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't tell you how to switch to Bing aerial imagery in MapBox. This sounds like a new question, if not already answered by the documentation or the Internet in general.

Comment: Thanks @scai. I will try to figure this out meanwhile.